# I'm trying to make a program but the "if" statement is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that uses text files to sort items using a barcode scanner...but the `if` statement is not working. You have 2 options:

1. create new barcode or
2. scan an existing barcode

but if I put the number in it does not work can anyone please help?

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkK3j.png)

Comment: The `input()` statement returns a string, but you are comparing it to an integer.

Comment: [Stackoverflow discourages screenshots of code and errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping an `int()` around your `input()` should fix your problem.